# How can I get a parameter passed in the url?

Tags: python, url, flask, urllib2

I am making a stock application, where, after a user types in a stock such as `MSFT`, they are redirected to `.../stock?s=MSFT` I have successfully made this part, but now I need Python to grab this current, unique URL so that I can parse the quote (in this case, the `MSFT`) out if it and save it as a new variable.

The easiest way I can think of is just to get the current URL, although I cannot seem to find a way to do this; using `self.request...` but this returned the error:

```
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

The other ideas I came across was to use a form of `urllib` as it contains a specific `.request_qs()` method, although this requires me to pass the URL as a parameter, which should be unique every time because of the change in stock.

Here is the Python I currently have:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home_search():
    if request.method == 'POST':
            st = request.form['s']
            return redirect(url_for('stock')+'?s='+st)

    return render_template('stk.html') 

@app.route('/stock', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def stock():
    #here I need to save the variable 'name' as the current URL. I can parse it later.
    url="http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="+name"&f=snl1"
    text=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

    return render_template('stock.html')
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: More code please. Looks like you're mixing methods and functions :)

Comment: I added an answer. Why exactly did you think of `self.request` if you already use the `request` object in `home_search`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. It's `request` (imported from the flask package), not `self.request`
2. The Flask docs have, as always, thorough documentation about variables in the URL: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#variable-rules

   ```
   @app.route('/user/<username>')
   def show_user_profile(username):
       # show the user profile for that user
       return 'User %s' % username
   ```

On that occasion, you should read the whole Quickstart from the Flask docs: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted any info on where the error occurs :) And I can't see where you're trying to access `self.requests`.

Looking at other Flask apps, it seems you should just access `request` instead.

Take a look at these examples: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples

Comment: Where I now have the comment about where I need to get the URL is where I tried `name = self.requests` – I will replicate that error now and post it again in more detail.

Comment: You just have to access the `request` variable instead :) I think you're pretty close